# how to drop superuser in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have created a new user with superuser role the rentdb, when i try to drop i will get there is dependency with it relating to some pg functions.
Is there a way i can delete rentdb completely.

```
  postgres-# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 rentdb    | Superuser                                                  | {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droprole.html) you can either [drop everything](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html) that the user owns:

```
drop owned by rentdb cascade;
```

or [assign](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) those objects to a different user:

```
reassign owned by rentdb to postgres;
```